# Increase file size infopath library SharePoint Online

Tags: document-library, infopath, sharepoint-online, office-365, custom-form

I am working with an InfoPath form library and business requirements call for an occasional large file to be uploaded to the form, however it will not allow over 6MB.  Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its by design and You can't change that for SharePoint Online.

http://community.office365.com/en-us/forums/148/t/74354.aspx

The only way I see around this is to upload the large files in another document library separately, not inside the InfoPath form.

For on premisses it can be changed:

Increasing maxRequestLength of HttpRuntime in web.config or machine.config will fix it.